# Connect Azure app service to SQL Server VM using Windows auth?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to connect from a web app (azure app service) to a SQL Server VM in Azure using Windows authentication? I'm not exactly sure if I need to impersonate or if the app needs to run under the identity that has access to the DB on the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this - but you will need to share a Active Directory between the two - or have then in a private network together so that they are in the same broadcast subnet.

If you need to use your own Active Directory the create a network and a VPN to your site.

If you don't need to use Active Directory then use SQL Auth.

Comment: I have the apps connected to a subnet with my AD domain on it. I can connect to the SQL servers over the vnet with the private IP from the apps. The problem is that I cannot use integrated security since the app isn't running under a user in my domain. "Server= localhost; Database= employeedetails; Integrated Security=True;"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible, although it may be with Azure SQL. But not a VM running MSSQL. Ref links below.

[SQL Server Integrated Security from an Azure Web Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078663/sql-server-integrated-security-from-an-azure-web-site)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/